# Report on polls

Tags: reporting, chatter, chatter-feed

I need a report on chatter polls which contains the `available choices` *(e.g: yes or no)* and how many people voted 
`yes` or `no` on the polls.

Answer (score 2):

Easy bounty for me :P : You cant do this as of today

Upvote for this idea.

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000jTFmAAM

Answer (score 0):

Until the reporting idea gets delivered, you can get the poll choice and voting information via the API:

[FeedPollChoice](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_feedpollchoice.htm)

[FeedPollVote](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_feedpollvote.htm)